# Heroku cannot find Postgres JDBC Driver

Tags: java, postgresql, maven, heroku, jdbc

Writing a pure Java server app for Heroku using Maven.
Connecting to Heroku's Postgres database.
Everything works when running **locally**, using IntelliJ's config for running Java apps, specifying Heroku's DB URL as an environment variable. The app works, and I can connect to the DB.
*Note: I found out that IntelliJ somehow automatically uses its own Postgres driver, the one that I specified in pom.xml gets ignored, obviously*
However, when I **deploy** the app, i get the following error in my Heroku log as soon as I connect to the DB:
`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver`

I followed the Heroku tutorial, but when I saw that there is no connection, I put

```
Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
```

before

```
String dbUrl = System.getenv("JDBC_DATABASE_URL");
return DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl);
```

just to make sure the driver gets found. If I remove `Class.forName()...` check, I get the `no suitable driver found for` *[my db url]* error.
Concerning the last error, I tried both **JDBC_DATABASE_URL** and **DATABASE_URL** env vars, and even constructing the DB URL "by hand", with `sslmode=require` etc, but still no luck.
My pom.xml has *modelVersion, groupId, artifactId, version* and *name* specified, as well as:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.4.1208</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

My Procfile, that Heroku uses to launch the app, looks like this:

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -cp target/classes:"target/dependency/*" Main --port $PORT
```

When I deploy the app, I get no errors, build is successful.

What can be the cause of the driver not loading? Am I forgetting something in pom.xml, or Procfile, or something else?

Comment: To clarify, when you add the `Class.forName` call, does the DB connection work?

Comment: locally, `forName()` catches the IntelliJ's jdbc driver and the connection works. On Heroku, `forName()` triggers the `ClassNotFoundException`

Comment: Can you check if the postgres jar file is in your Heroku slug by running `heroku run ls target/dependency/`?

Comment: I get `ls: cannot access target/dependency/: No such file or directory`

Comment: That would suggest your JAR files are not being vendored (i.e. copied into the target directory during the build). Are you deploying with `git push` or `mvn heroku:deploy`?

Comment: I am pushing to heroku using IntelliJ, therefore - using the git client, `git push`. I can try `mvn heroku:deploy`

Comment: It worked! Thanks a ton, @codefinger, for solving the mystery that lasted a couple of days!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes, convenience (like using IntelliJ's git integration to push to Heroku like I did) leads to unwanted problems.

I used `git push` to update my app on Heroku. Everything was fine, except the required libraries didn't fall into place.
Tried `mvn heroku:deploy`, tested, everything works! Thanks [codefinger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/63308/codefinger) for the suggestion.

If anyone asks, here's how you do it if never done before:
1) Add the [Heroku Maven Plugin](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-java-applications-with-the-heroku-maven-plugin) to your `pom.xml`:

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.heroku.sdk</groupId>
                <artifactId>heroku-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.6</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

2) Execute maven goal `heroku:deploy`.
That's it

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with connection working from local system, but not when deployed. Was the same issue, not having dependencies accessible, but for a build using a JAR, I just needed to make sure that I used a JAR that was self contained with all dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

There is a more direct solution than switching to `heroku-maven-plugin`: you can mark the postgresql dependency as having `runtime` scope:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.3.1</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The default scope is `compile`, which results in Maven leaving it out since it's not referenced in the code.

I've added this answer because I ran into the same issue but had a lot of trouble with the `heroku-maven-plugin` approach (my project has multiple modules and that complicates things).  Adopting the plugin probably has other benefits, but configuring the dependency's scope was a much simpler fix in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting Heroku Help:

> This means you have parsed the DATABASE_URL wrong. You need to change
> postgres to postgresql in the connection string (JDBC does not support
> the "postgres" shorthand), or use the JDBC_DATABASE_URL config
> variable instead.

[Also, make sure the dependency is runtime only](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70491259/819651).

[source](https://help.heroku.com/51QYCRMZ/why-is-there-no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbc-postgres)