# 'java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver fround' [SQLException, Heroku, Postgresql]

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, heroku, sqlexception

I am currently trying to deploy an old project of mine to heroku.
Locally everything work perfect. (also with the amazonaws psql database provided by heroku).
But as soon as I try to deploy the application to heroku, I get this (see below) error in the heroku console.

Note: some letters are replaced with 'x'

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://xxx-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:5432/dxxxx5xx6xxxxx
```

[image]

To connect the Java Application to the postgresql database I do:

```java
     String jdbcURL = System.getenv("DATABASE_SERVER");
            String username = System.getenv("DATABASE_USERNAME");
            String password = System.getenv("DATABASE_PASSWORD");

            try {
                connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcURL, username, password);

                System.out.println("Verbindung zur Datenbank hergestellt");

                statement = connection.createStatement();

            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Full code can be seen here:

https://github.com/ConfusingBot/bot/blob/master/src/de/confusingbot/manage/sql/SQLManager.java

The env variables are defined in heroku and local. And local everything works fine with the same variables.
[image]

pom.xml:
https://github.com/ConfusingBot/bot/blob/master/pom.xml

Thank you

Edited:
I found out that the postgres dependency does exist in heroku.. (see image below) But soemhow the driver can't be found..
[image]
[Heroku cannot find Postgres JDBC Driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36683006/heroku-cannot-find-postgres-jdbc-driver)

But unfortunately in my case their fix doesn't work :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building the jar which includes all dependencies works quite fine..
for that we have to define a plugin in the pom.xml and thats it.. (see below)

```java
<plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>de.confusingbot.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Thanks for the hint: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56800302/14108895